# ffmpeg: Placing an overlay over multiple images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing, linux

I am trying to overlay a png image onto a series of images (a few hundred images), I will later take this series of images with the overlay and construct a movie out of the series of images. I don't know too much about ffmpeg and I have just recently started playing with it for converting and editing media files but I have found something that works for combining the png with one tif image:

**ffmpeg -i my.png -i my.tif -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -ac 2 output.tif**

This is what I have so far, which allows me to overlay my png on a single tif image. I would like to do this for every single tif image that I have in my folder (hundreds) of tif images.

Is there a way to instruct ffmpeg to do such a process?

Thanks

Comment: Are all the TIFFs with the same properties, like resolution?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, the resolution of all of the tif images and the png image is the same. Specifically these images are electron micrographs and I was hoping to overlay a graphic on top of all of the electron micrographs. I was able to generate a macro on ImageJ to overlay the graphic onto all of the tifs. However, I am still curious if there is a way to accomplish this type of "water-marking" with ffmpeg as that may prove to be useful in the future. I suppose that I would need a conditional statement for the tif images, but I am not sure how to implement such a thing in ffmpeg.

Comment: How are the TIFFs named?

Comment: @Gyan The tif images are all organized by their capture frame in a numerical sequence. Eg. image0001.tif, image0002.tif, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all TIFFs have the same properties, and are named sequentially like image0001.tif, then you can use

```
ffmpeg -i image%04d.tif -i my.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay" out%04d.tif
```

This will generate images with the overlay named as follows

```
out0001.tif
out0002.tif
...
```